# combining getChildAt with addChild

Tags: actionscript-3

i have the following code:

```
seatContainer.getChildAt(order.seats[i])
```

i want to add a child to this but it doesnt allow me, i can only add an eventListener to this.

Anyone know how i can add a child to this without using an eventListener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, `getChildAt()` from the container classes (e.g. VBox, HBox, etc.) returns a DisplayObject.  This object type does not have methods such as "addChild" -- these methods are introduced further down the inheritance hierarchy.

You'll need to cast the referenced returned by the `getChildAt()` method to something other than DisplayObject; I believe the method you want is in DisplayObjectContainer:

```
var child:DisplayObject = seatContainer.getChildAt(order.seats[i]);
(child as DisplayObjectContainer).addChild(your_child_class_here);
```

Comment: That's correct. If you're intending to use child later on, then you might prefer to cast the getChildAt command - var child:DisplayObjectContainer = (seatContainer.getChildAt(order.seats[i]) as DisplayObjectContainer);

Comment: @Roy, yeah that's what I would do, though I would also cast it to the original container which was added in the first place (e.g. HBox, VBox, or whatever).